# Ubuntu : Filesystem for media storage

Tags: filesystem, storage

I just bought a 2TB hard disk for redundancy purposes. I have 1 HD failing, so I need to backup my data on this one. Which is a good filesystem for long term data storage. Data includes, photos, videos, movies, etc. 
I am looking for some options where the HD life is extended to maximum. 
I have tried XFS before on one of 2TB hard disk, but there are many images/videos which are corrupt now, even though I routinely perform fsck on them. 
Thank you.

Comment: Linux access only?

Comment: Related question on U&L: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180753/linux-file-system-for-an-external-hdd

Comment: @RoVo : yes, For windows, I have a external drive with ntfs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NTFS format.
Why?
because the max size of a single file that can be stored on a FAT32-formatted HDD is 4GB (on NTFS Maximum file size: 16 TB), that means if you have to store a 9GB movie, you won't be will be able to store that on this.
on the other hand, NTFS is supported by Windows, Mac, and Linux.
FAT32 formateed drives are more vulnerable to disk errors.